# PopupMenu with checkableBehavior="single" group ignores setCheck() on items

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a **PopupMenu** define in XML below being part of a **Fragment**

```
<menu xmlns:com.itrash.android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:id="@+id/order_by_menu" android:checkableBehavior="single">
   <item android:id="@+id/action_show_discounts_only"
         android:title="@string/discounts_only_title" />

   <item android:id="@+id/action_show_all"
         android:title="@string/all_title" />      
</group>
```

The menu is linked to **ImageButton** (snippet from **onActionCreated()** )

```
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        
    this.onlyDiscounts = prefs.getBoolean(PROPERTY_ONLY_DISCOUNTS, false);
    this.orderBy = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_ORDER_BY, ORDER_BY_NAME); 


this.filterButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.filter_button);       
    this.filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            filterMenu.show();              
        }
    });                
    this.filterMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), getActivity().findViewById(R.id.filter_button));
    this.filterMenu.inflate(R.menu.product_filter_menu);
    this.filterMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            onFilterClick(item);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When clicked the following method is called

```
private void onFilterClick(MenuItem item) {
    boolean showDiscountsOnly = item.getItemId() == R.id.action_show_discounts_only ? true : false;

    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());             

    if (this.onlyDiscounts != showDiscountsOnly) {
        this.onlyDiscounts = showDiscountsOnly;

        productSearchResultAdapter.clear();

        this.curPage = 1;

        doSearchProducts();
    }

    final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(PROPERTY_ONLY_DISCOUNTS, showDiscountsOnly);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Problem I am facing is how to restore state of menu items according to attribute **onlyDiscounts** when retrieved from **SharedPreferences**?
In other words I want to have the menu item *action_show_discounts_only* checked if **onlyDiscounts** is true.

I have tried to place inside **onActionCreated()** something along the lines

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.filterMenu.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = this.filterMenu.getMenu().getItem(i);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_show_discounts_only) {
            item.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            item.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

or even

```
this.filterMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_show_discounts_only).setChecked(this.onlyDiscounts);
```

this.filterMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_show_all).setChecked(!this.onlyDiscounts);

Both attempts were ignored, *R.id.action_show_all* item  is always check no matter what value **onlyDiscounts** is.

Any idea how to resolve this?